# revision edit upvote

Tags: support, up-votes

I have someoene who revisioned or edited my question on Writers, can I give them points for them spending there time to make the edit? I know they get automatic credit for it, but can we give credit to show how 'good' we think the edit is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no mechanism to do this - and members making great edits are doing so more for its own sake than for reputation.

You can ping him in a comment and thank him for the revision.

Comment: Encouraging the *thank you* comments is frowned upon on SE. The more common response to *how do I show appreciation* is *do other things that improve the content*... pay it forward.